# How to make a variable NULL?

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to store some hidden Form element values as variables. Sometimes these hidden fields do not have a value at all.

In the situation where a hidden field does not have a value, the Jquery variable is returning `0` as the value when I actually want `null`.

Why do I want `null`? Because it's being passed to a database and storing `0` is incorrect. It should insert `null`.

So how can I get JQuery to return/store `null` and not `0`?

Comment: Your database columns need to be nullable before you can insert null values into them...

Comment: Hidden fields will have string values. So if the value is empty, jQuery's `$().val()` will return `""` (the empty string) rather than 0. So there must be something in your code (show us!) that converts the empty string into `0`... see example: http://jsbin.com/iNeRiVUg/1

Comment: This might be the same as 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852794/how-to-assign-null-value-to-hidden-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hidden field always has a value. If you haven't specified one, it's an empty string.

You can't put null as a value of a hidden field, so you need to handle the empty values either in the code that sends the information to the server, or in the code on the server.